# React-router server side match translated routes?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-router, locale, universal

I'm using react-router for server side rendering and I have locale information stored in a `locales.json` file. The locale information is only set after a response from an api call, which includes the current language, i.e. `'GB', 'NO', 'FR', etc.`, which then completes the server response and everything is fired through to the client in the correct language.

However, I'm using the `react-router` `match` method:

```
match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => { ... }
```

...and I need the `routes` to be based off the language from the api response, i.e.

```
// Route
<Route path={`:storeId/${locales[language].path}`} />

// locale.json
{
  "GB": {
    "path": "contact"
  },
  "NO": {
    "path": "kontakt"
  }
}
```

Is this approach possible? It's like I need to define routes after the api call is made, but to make the api call, I need routes defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I haven't tried your example specifically, but it is definitly possible to define routes from an api response and pass it to the "match" function.

You could try something as following:

```
function handleServerRendering(req, res) {

  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/myCutomeRoutes')
   .then(function(response){

     const myRoutes = {
       routes: response.data,
       location: req.url
     }

     match(myRoutes, function(error, redirectLocation, routeContext) {
      // WRITE YOUR CODE IN HERE...
     })
   })
   .catch(function(err){
     console.log('error', err);
   })
}
```

As you can see, you firstly do an API call and then you pass the response.data to routes inside "myRoutes" constant